# Stopping ARP protocol in window

Tags: java, window, arp, jnetpcap

Is there a way to stop ARP protocol in window , i have developed my own ARP protocol which add authentication to ARP using a java api called jnetpcap. but , still haven't found a way to stop the normal ARP.
now i am deleting the ARP entry updated from the normal arp request  protocol but still i need to stop my machine from sending reply to those request.

Comment: I do not care if the solution require inserting adding fire wall in my computer that intercept the arp packet , i need the fire wall to stop the arp packet which has size <60 my arp size is 72

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See this , it is simple packet filter add its source to stop arp.
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/5602/Simple-Packet-Filter-Firewall

Answer (score 2):

You can try to create a new DWORD key in

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\Tcpip\Parameters
```

with the name `ArpRetryCount` and set it to 0.

Comment: I have tried that and it didn't work, also after reviewing the documentation of ARPRetrycount i found it is used to determine how many time tcp send  gratuitous Address Request Packet and not the number of reply.